# Blocking applications using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a web application which will allow users to take exam online. When the user clicks on take test I need to block the calculator app. Is there a way to do that?

I am using asp.net,c#,visual studio 2008

Comment: Just consider if it where possible for a random site to do anything on your computer.

Comment: Not with ASP.NET (or Silverlight, Flash).

Comment: The next logical step would be to try to write a web application that prevents the user from using a hand calculator.  It's a pretty deep rabbit hole :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely not. Your code is executing on your server, and the calculator is running on their PC. You can send JavaScript, Flash, Silverlight, etc. that is executed, but they run in a sandbox - can't affect anything outside the browser runtime. You wouldn't like it very much if websites could manipulate your PC would you?

Comment: @HaraHara no, not unless that application has itself installed hooks that either allow special scripts to be called from the browser, or registers a new protocol (i.e. `myapp://command`)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible unless you force the user to install custom software on their computer. And if we go into that, this has nothing to do with the web anymore.

And to be honest, if you don't have any control over the environment the user is in... what's preventing them from opening whatever software you're trying to block on a laptop sitting next to the computer running the exam?

Answer (score 1):

if you are in a Web application, you cant control your `client machine`. Only you can control your browser by using javascript or silverlight etc.

You have to install some extra windows application to protect that